# Blender Old UV applied on top of new UV

Tags: texturing, uv

I've been doing something that may seem weird.

My workflow has been separate objects using loop cut into separate faces. I then use UV to apply a texture to all of these faces. It has been working fine for 2 different maps I've done, but now it's glitching in a weird way. In the photo you can see the outer wall, and a glitching inner wall. The inner wall is not any different than the outer one and was copied from it pre-uv and loop cuts. The outer walls are overlapping in the same way as the inner ones, and everything I do with the inner walls, they keep breaking the textures and applying both a Unwrap and (unwrap) reset texture simultaneously.

This is happening whether the inner walls are overlapping each other or not. So it is nothing to do with the face that they are intersecting as far as I can tell.

Anyone care to explain to me what is going on? Only certain walls are refusing to apply the uv map correctly and there is very little difference between the ones that are and the ones that aren't.

[image]

I've added the file here. This isn't the one I took a picture of, but the house in the middle has a wall that is doing the same thing as the the hedges.

[image: Something wrong with UV reset or UV Unwrap]

Comment: Without the Blend file very difficult to guess. But do I get the problem right that when you modify the UV map of the inner wall, you also get a modification of the UV map of the outer wall, which you don't want? If so, check if those meshes are instances of each other. Select one of the walls, activate the Mesh Data tab. If there is a number written in front of the 'F', then this mesh is an instance of another. Click the number to make them unique.

Comment: I've added the blend file. Different map, same problem with the structure in the middle. I looked at the Mesh Data tab and there is only one listing under UV Maps and it doesn't have an F...It doesn't look like it's a duplication issue. But then again I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with how blender is resetting the uv map and it's putting the whole face as a plane as well as every separate tile? Is that even possible?

Comment: When uploading, please remember to pack reference images into the Blend, otherwise the model is going to be all pink. Anyways, we are talking about the house or the maze? The maze seems to be ok, on the house you have a modelling issue which can be fixed easily.

Comment: resetting UVs means to take each polygon and unwrap it separately so it fills the whole UV space. It's a bit different to other applications, but can be useful in some scenarios

Comment: Sorry about that. Blend file should be packed now. I seperated the uv map and found there is one face that overlaps the others on the wall with an issue. The maze is okay now since I redid it differently, but I'm having the same issue with the house wall in the middle.

Shouldn't the UV map not redo a face it has already done?

Comment: I've added an answer now showing what the modelling issue is I spoke about before.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is this:

[image: flicker]

This flickering can have a few reasons, in your case it is an accident that happened while modelling. You duplicated that wall and left the duplicate in the same place. It has a different UV Map than the original, so both walls try to show their (different) texture to the viewer, resulting in a heavy fight.

To resolve it, delete one of the walls. Select one arbitrary face, and run the **Select Linked** command. Then delete those selected faces:

[image: delete linked]

Do this for all problem walls, and make sure to check the ones that seem right as well. As long as the UV Map is identical, you might not spot the issue at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did change how I was duplicating walls so this all makes alot of sense.